# How to prevent word breaking in React Native?

Tags: react-native

It seems like an obvious question, but I can't figure out how to prevent React Native Text components from breaking individual words when they don't fit in the width of the container, while also keeping word wrapping in general. It seems a weird default to break words - how do I prevent it?

Here's some example code:

```
  <View style={{
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
  }}>
    <Text
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        // flexWrap: "nowrap", // did nothing
        // flexShrink: 1, // did nothing
        fontSize: 10,
        lineHeight: 16,
        // whiteSpace: "nowrap", // did nothing
      }}
    >Hereisareallylongwordina block with shorter words.</Text>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Common reason is using strict `width: xx` or `flex: 1` which creates firm borders for text and compresses it.

Instead you can use `<View style={{minWidth: 50}}>` to let text inside be wider

Or `<Text numberOfLines={1} >` to cut 2nd line (then `...` will be used at the end of word).

Answer (score -1):

Please use:

whiteSpace: 'nowrap'

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything at all - is it supposed to be on the <Text style> element?

Comment: As of React Native 0.64.x, `whiteSpace` is not a valid style property. In addition, `white-space: 'nowrap'` in CSS does not affects individual words, which seems to be the OP concern here, e.g. individual words being broken when the container is too narrow. There is a `textBreakStrategy` prop for Text component, but it doesn't prevent words from being broken.